# R: Aggregate data in sliding window into new columns

Tags: r, dplyr

let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), v1 = c(3, 5, 1, 0, 1), v2 = c(10, 6, 1, 20, 23), Time = c(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 10:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 11:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 13:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 16:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1900-01-01 20:00:00"))) %>% group_by(ID)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID    v1    v2 Time               
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1     1     3    10 1900-01-01 10:00:00
2     1     5     6 1900-01-01 11:00:00
3     1     1     1 1900-01-01 13:00:00
4     1     0    20 1900-01-01 16:00:00
5     1     1    23 1900-01-01 20:00:00
```

In words, this is a simple timeseries of a specific `ID` with two values `v1` and `v2` per time.
As quite common in machine learning, I want to aggregate the last `n` timesteps into one feature vector. For all previous timesteps there should be a time reference in hours when this data point occured. For the first row, where no previous timestep is available, the data should be filled with zeros.

Let's make an example. In this case n=2, that is I want to aggregate the current time step (t2) and the prevopus (t1) together:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
     ID v1_t1 v2_t1 time_t1 v1_t2 v2_t2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0      NA     3    10
2     1     3    10       1     5     6
3     1     5     6       2     1     1
4     1     1     1       3     0    20
5     1     0    20       4     1    23
```

I want to keep that as generic as possible, so that n can change and the number of data columns. Any idea how to do this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::lag` and `dplyr::across` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn=FALSE)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(time_t1 = lubridate::hour(Time) - lag(lubridate::hour(Time))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(v1, v2), .fns = list(t2 = ~.x, t1 = ~lag(.x, default = 0)))) %>% 
  select(-v1, -v2, -Time)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID time_t1 v1_t2 v1_t1 v2_t2 v2_t1
#>   <dbl>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1      NA     3     0    10     0
#> 2     1       1     5     3     6    10
#> 3     1       2     1     5     1     6
#> 4     1       3     0     1    20     1
#> 5     1       4     1     0    23    20
```

**UPDATE** Here is a more generic approach which makes use of some function factories to create list of functions which could then be passed to the `.fns` argument of `across`. Haven't tested for the more general case but should work for any `n` or number of lags to include and also for any number of data columns.

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn=FALSE)

fun_factory1 <- function(n) {
  function(x) {
    lubridate::hour(x) - lag(lubridate::hour(x), n = n)
  }
}

fun_factory2 <- function(n) {
  function(x) {
    lag(x, n = n, default = 0)
  }
}

n <- 2

fns1 <- lapply(seq(n - 1), fun_factory1)
names(fns1) <- paste0("t", seq(n - 1))

fns2 <- lapply(seq(n) - 1, fun_factory2)
names(fns2) <- paste0("t", seq(n))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(Time, .fns = fns1)) %>%
  mutate(across(c(v1, v2), .fns = fns2)) %>% 
  select(-v1, -v2, -Time)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID Time_t1 v1_t1 v1_t2 v2_t1 v2_t2
#>   <dbl>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1      NA     3     0    10     0
#> 2     1       1     5     3     6    10
#> 3     1       2     1     5     1     6
#> 4     1       3     0     1    20     1
#> 5     1       4     1     0    23    20
```

Comment: my bad. In this case the time_t1 indeed matches with the row number. However in general, time_t1 should be the difference in hours between the timestamp of t1 and t2 for every row

Comment: Not a big deal. We could use lubridate::hour. See my edit.

Comment: first of all, thanks for that answer. I think this works! However, is there any way to keep this more generic. That is I simply want to switch to n=3 meaning that I want to consider t1, t2, t3

Comment: Whether the extra effort is worthwhile depends on how much lags or n's you would include. But see my update for an approach to generalize my approach to any n and number of data columns.